# Problem with breadcrumb on forum

Tags: nodes, breadcrumbs

I am using Drupal 7, and I want to show the breadcrumb only on the forum, so I used the following code:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if (arg(0) == 'forum' || $node->type == 'forum') print $breadcrumb;
```

The code works, but it gives errors when I visit the admin page.

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 18 of /srv/www/lusciousanime.com/public_html/sites/all/themes/anime/page.tpl.php).

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because, when you visit a page that is not a node page, `menu_get_object()` (when called without arguments) doesn't return any value. The function could not return any value in other cases too, or not return an object, if the load function returns `FALSE`, as the code executed from the function is the following one.

```
  $router_item = menu_get_item($path);
  if (isset($router_item['load_functions'][$position]) && !empty($router_item['map'][$position]) && $router_item['load_functions'][$position] == $type . '_load') {
    return $router_item['map'][$position];
  }
```

Your code should be similar to the following one:

```
$node = menu_get_object();

if (arg(0) == 'forum' || (!empty($node) && $node->type == 'forum')) {
  print $breadcrumb;
}
```